# Determine a vector given vector the scalar and vector projection

Tags: linear-algebra

Determine the vector(s) whose vector projection on $u = \langle1,2,2\rangle$,  is $v =\langle 3,6,6 \rangle$ and its
scalar projection on $w =\langle1,1,1\rangle$ is $√3.$

I am really stuck on this question. The only thing I know is to start off with the unknown vector to be $\langle a,b,c\rangle$. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The [vector projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection) $v$ on $u$ of a vector $x$ is given by the formula
$$
v=\frac{(x,u)}{\|u\|^2}\;u=(3,6,6).
$$
By [scalar projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_projection) of $x$ on $w$, you probably mean
$$
\frac{(x,w)}{\|w\|}=\sqrt{3}.
$$
Now writing $x=(a,b,c)$ and computing the above formulae will lead you to a set of two linear equations in $a,b,c$.

Comment: So I did that and got $a+b+c = 3$ for one equation using the scalar projection, but I'm not too sure for the vector projection one

Comment: Simply, $(x,u)=a+2b+2c$ and $\|u\|^2=9$. Looking at one coordinate is enough. Say the first one. On the left, you have $\frac{a+2b+2c}{9}\cdot 1$. On the right, you have $3$. Just equate them.

Comment: Would  the other one be $a + 2b + 2c = 0$?

Comment: No, I think it is $a+2b+2c=27$.

Comment: SO $a = -24$?, but how would $b$ and $c$ be found since  we can't isolate them because  they have the same coefficient

Comment: No $a=6-27=-21$. And $b+c=3-a=24$. There are infinitely many solutions: $X=(a,b,c)=(-21,b,24-b)$ where $B$ can take any real value. This is an affine line.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense! Thank you very much!